# SSRS 2008 Center External Image

Tags: reporting-services

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create a report and I have an image control that I want to
display come from External source, The actual image sizes are rather large and are not resizeable. I set my image control size width:5.20834 int and height:2.25 int and i want to image fit the image control i have set the sizing to "FitProportional" but however the image are not centerd. I am try as the following article

```
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrishays/archive/2004/10/27/centeredimages.aspx

http://romiller.com/2008/05/09/horizontally-centred-dynamic-images-in-ssrs/#respon
```

d

but not work for me my example bellow are the link to my images

```
http://i58.tinypic.com/2nscox4.jpg
http://i61.tinypic.com/2e48z6q.jpg
```

Comment: Is your image component inside another control or placed on the body of the report?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the quick reply. I place the image control on the body of the report.